# 3 pins digital switch component for an Arduino project

Tags: arduino, switches, i2c

I am trying to use a digital switch component to switch on/off SCL lines of some I2C sensors. On proteus, I can perfectly simulate that with a component name DSWITCH as shown on the attached picture. [image: using Proteus DSWITCH from the DSIMMDLS library to switch on/off SCL lines]

Now, when it comes to physically building this circuit, what component can I use to achieve this switching programmatically just like in my simulation?

Comment: Most obvious is a mosfet. Maybe ssr. Or try spst/spdt. But why would you do that?

Comment: I'm guessing that you want to do this because you want to connect up multiple I2C devices, all with the same I2C address. The elegant way to work around this problem is to use an I2C multiplexer.

Comment: @GregoryKornblum Since I am connecting multiple slave sensor devices on a single SDA-SCL line(each device will have its set of pins that we can call a channel) I would like to be able to tell which sensor is at which channel(or position) by switching on/off one by one

Comment: @brhans not necessarily with the same address

Comment: Even so, I still lean towards the I2C multiplexer ... Seems like less risk/work to me.

Comment: @brhans can you please give me more details on how the multiplexer works or direct me to some material apart from the datasheet?

Comment: [Adafruit](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-tca9548a-1-to-8-i2c-multiplexer-breakout/overview) has a short description for their I2C Mux breakout board which gives an overview of what the device does. "this multiplexer acts as a gatekeeper, shuttling the commands to the selected set of I2C pins with your command."

Comment: Aaaarrgh! @Olfredos6: Please turn off the grid when taking screengrabs. The text is not legible.

Comment: @Transistor sorry about that, please do take another look in a few, I'm updating the picture

Comment: TCA9548A 8-channel I2C switch.

Comment: Using a switch, how will you ensure that the SCL lines to your sensors are pulled up when the switch is off? Allowing SCL to float is not a good idea.

Comment: Good point! But I am not planning on leaving them floating for a long period of time to avoid unnecessary energy consumption. The SCL lines will only be switched off when required and turned back on as soon as let's say the configuration phase of a monitoring process is done

Comment: You must have a pullup R on SCL at each chip e.g 100k

Answer (score 1):

You want to use 74HC4066 , if you need single switch elements. You must have a high value pullup R on SCL at each chip e.g 100k

You might prefer to use a multiplexor like 74HC4051,2,3.

If you use a mux, then *only* one of n can work at once. If you use 4066s, then you can connect all or one. Sometimes you want to do this, as you can write to multiple chips which have the same address (e.g to initiate ADC read), but you can only read from one at a time.

If you use 74HC4052, you can switch both SCL and SDA. This is not needed for your basic task of muxing the I2C bus to 4 chips which are on the same pcb.

If you had more chips, or if one of the segments was on a long cable, or likely to have faults, then switching both lines keeps the C down, the timing matched between SDA and SCL, and can isolate a faulty segment allowing the rest of the sytem to operate.

---

Now, you can also use a dedicated [I2C mutliplexor like this](https://www.i2cchip.com/pdfs/BusSwitch_MUX3.pdf) , but just because chip makers produce chips, doesn't mean they are advantageous to you. Using ordinary cmos switches or muxes is

- electrically just fine, zero problems
- cheap
- uses a standard part that is useful for other things
- control is not over the same bus, so it cannot be blocked by an [I2C bus fault. (sec 3.1)](https://www.i2cchip.com/pdfs/BusSwitch_MUX3.pdf#page=6)

I2C switches have some advantages

- level shifting function
- can be ganged up to make enormous multiplexor arrays
- don't need extra control lines from your micro - good for external expansion modules like [this](https://www.i2cchip.com/pdfs/BusSwitch_MUX3.pdf)

---

Lastly a simple N-fet would also work. (Source to master SCL, Drain to slave, 100k pullup at slave). It doesn't isolate capacitances very well, but again, not an issue for 4 chips on one pcb.

Answer (score 0):

The CD4016B is a quad CMOS switch in a 14-pin package.

[image]

*Figure 1. CD4016B pinout. Source: [Intersil](https://www.intersil.com/en/products/space-and-harsh-environment/rad-hard-analog/rh-switches/CD4066BMS.html).*

The linked page has summary information and links to technical documents. Check that the voltage ratings and on-resistance match your requirements.

Comment: Thanks very much...this one seems helpful. However, I would like to be sure about the voltage ratings as u pointed out. On the link, it says: High Voltage Types (20V Rating)
15V Digital or ±7.5V Peak-to-Peak Switching, will an Arduino be able to drive this? since an Arduino can output/input 3.3 or 5volts if I am right. Please help clarify my understanding

Comment: The SCL lines on your microcontroller will be switching at 3.3 V or 5 V depending on the board and micro. The 4016 needs to be able to switch voltages in that range and the control inputs need to work at that voltage too. Here's the [4066](https://www.intersil.com/content/dam/Intersil/documents/cd40/cd4066bms.pdf) datasheet. It is the same pinout but has lower on resistance and so is a little better for some applications.

Comment: Thank you very much. I really appreciate. I will work on this tomorrow as soon as I get the IC then will come back to validate your answer. cheers

Comment: 74HC4066 is the variant you want to use. (CD4016/66 has high R).